# Return value doesn't convert a return value to json when a controller's return type is Mono of Interface, in webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

In Spring MVC framework, When controller returns a interface type, spring's message converter can convert the return value to a proper message(like a JSON).

For example, I could get a JSON message when I called 'vehicle' api.

```
    @GetMapping("vehicle")
    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
        return new Car();
    }

    public interface Vehicle {

    }

    public class Car implements Vehicle {
        private String gearType;
    }
```

But, Webflux's behavior is different. It only supports a 'content-type: text/event-stream' when return type is a mono of interface.

```
    @GetMapping("vehicle")
    public Mono<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return Mono.just(new Car());
    }
```

In my opinion, Webflux's behavior is uncomfortable. Is it a bug?
Do I need to add a custom MessageWriter to encode interface type?

Comment: Perhaps try declaring your controller method like it says in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestmapping-produces)?

Comment: @AndyBrown your meaning is that should I return only `Vehicle` instead `Mono<Vehicle>`?

Answer (score 0):

In annotated controllers, it's sufficient to return a `Vehicle` not a `Mono<Vehicle>` as described in [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-return-types).

**Note:** You can use the explicit handler functions when working with `Mono<T>`or `Flux<T>` since the handler functions are more explicit when working with reactive types. However, they are more verbose to use.